# Unable to resolve sbt 0.13.7

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to compile [Scala-KendoUI](https://github.com/thenewmotion/scala-kendoui) project in my local. But I am getting issues with sbt 0.13.7.

```
Host repo.typesafe.com not found. url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I am not able to find any solution for that anywhere else. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: It is [online](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml). Maybe a temporary hiccup.

Comment: I am able to see the jar file in the repo, but sbt is not finding it. Do I have to add some other resolvers?

Comment: No. Are you behind a proxy?